# Error on using Raycast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use the `Physics.Raycast` method, but I get errors saying:

> The best overloaded method match for 'UnityEngine.Physics.Raycast(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3, float, int)' has some invalid arguments.

It's strange because both itellisense and the documentation tell me that this is permitted:

```
RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, hit)) {
    print(hit.point.ToString());
    selection.transform.Translate(hit.point - selection.transform.position);
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need the out keyword before "hit" in Physics.Raycast(ray, hit).

```
RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
    print(hit.point.ToString());
    selection.transform.Translate(hit.point - selection.transform.position);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In C# we must use a precursor out parameter before the variable hit in
order to get the function to assign data to it.